# Bash Script: Mass Restore Files with Sleuthkit

Tags: bash, computer-forensics

I [found a bash script online](http://ixti.net/administration/2012/10/25/mass-restore-files-from-corrupted-media-with-sleuthkit.html) for mass-restoring files using the Sleuthkit but am having trouble using it due to what I believe is an error in the script itself. Here is the script:

```
IMAGE=$1
LIST=$2
DEST=$3

cat $LIST | while read line; do
   filetype=`echo "$line" | awk {'print $1'}`
   filenode=`echo "$line" | awk {'print $2'}`
   filenode=${filenode%:}
   filename=`echo "$line" | cut -f 2 -d '   '`

   if [ $filetype == "r/r" ]; then
      echo "$filename"
      mkdir -p "`dirname "$DEST/$filename"`"
      icat -f ext2 -r -s $IMAGE "$filenode" > "$DEST/$filename"
   fi
done
```

Everything works fine until the `cut` statement, which throws this error:

```
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
```

Obviously the script is trying to use a string as a delimiter which the cut command does not allow. However, this isn't necessary as the output is actually tab-delimited. However, removing the delimiter produces this error message:

```
[: 16: r/r: unexpected operator
```

For every line. The input (the LIST file) looks like this:

```
r/r 8457-128-3: Architects list.docx
r/r 90219-128-4:    ACID Pro 7.0 Projects/Track 2 - 3.sfk
r/r 90208-128-4:    ACID Pro 7.0 Projects/Track 2 - 3.wav
r/r 192969-128-3:   OLD SCHOOL PAPERS/Doc Comp.docx
```

The output of `awk {'print $1'}` is one or the other of these two lines:

```
r/r
d/d
```

The output of `awk {'print $2'}` is the file inodes, like this:

```
134164-128-1:
233761-128-1:
129177-128-1:
23963-128-1:
```

My suspicion was that the colon (:) was the problem so I removed it by piping the filenode to a `sed` statement that got rid of the colon, but that also didn't fix the problem. So after modifying this line to repair the first issue:

```
   filename=`echo "$line" | cut -f 2 -d '   '`
```

To:

```
   filename=`echo "$line" | cut -f 2`
```

And even after removing the colon from the file inode number, I am still stuck with this error:

```
[: 16: r/r: unexpected operator
```

The script was written for an ext2 file system but I am using it on an NTFS file system. I have modified the necessary lines and can get the `icat` command to work as written, so it is not an issue of not changing the relevant portions (the individual lines work fine, I've debugged this as well as I know how).

Here is my current script:

```
IMAGE=/dev/sdb
LIST=files.lst
DEST=~/Desktop/sol/backup

cat $LIST | while read line; do
   filetype=`echo "$line" | awk {'print $1'}`
   filenode=`echo "$line" | awk {'print $2'}`
   filenode=${filenode%:}
   filename=`echo "$line" | cut -f 2`

   if [ $filetype == "r/r" ]; then
      echo "$filename"
      mkdir -p "`dirname "$DEST/$filename"`"
      icat -f ntfs -o 409600 -r -s $IMAGE "$filenode" > "$DEST/$filename"
   fi
done
```

So that's all the troubleshooting and thinking I've done so far. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I was asked to show the output of `cat -vte $LIST`, which is as follows (sample):

```
r/r 284268-128-4:^IVirtualDJ/Skins/VirtualDJ 7 (6 Decks).zip$
r/r 284265-128-4:^IVirtualDJ/Skins/VirtualDJ5.zip$
d/d 284231-144-6:^IVirtualDJ/Tracklisting$
r/r 284345-128-4:^IVirtualDJ/Tracklisting/2013-06-21.m3u$
d/d 15695-144-1:^IMy Music$
r/r 14970-128-3:^IDemotivational pics.docx$
r/r 1677-128-1:^Idesktop.ini$
r/r 881-128-4:^IDocument 1.doc$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your tab delimited file like this:

```
while  IFS=$' \t:' read filetype filenode filename; do
    if [ "$filetype" = "r/r" ]; then
       echo "$filename"
       mkdir -p "`dirname "$DEST/$filename"`"
       icat -f ntfs -o 409600 -r -s $IMAGE "$filenode" > "$DEST/$filename"
    fi
done < $LIST
```

Comment: btw your question is already well documented and I upvoted it too

Comment: Could the colons be the issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41989/discussion-between-dan-and-anubhava)

Comment: Bounty awarded. Thanks again!